# What does the tilde ("$\sim$") mean in $\tan^{-1}\frac{M_1\sim M_2}{M_1+M_2}$?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, inverse-function, angle

[image]

$$  \theta_{} \leq \pi/2  $$

$~ H_{x} ~$ can be positive or negative but $~ H_{y} ~$  can be assumed which takes only upward vertical value.

$$  \tan \left( \theta_{}  \right) = \frac{  H_{x}  }{  H_{y}  } = \frac{ \left( M_{1}-M_{2} \right) }{  \left( M_{1}+M_{2} \right)   }   $$

The problem has been provoked from the below equation.

$$  \therefore ~~  \left| \theta_{}  \right| = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  M_{1}  \sim  M_{2}  }{   \left( M_{1}+M_{2} \right)  }  \right)  $$

What it this "$~ \sim ~$"? misprint? Or a new conception for me? How should I interpret it ?

Moreover, I've been confused of bars of $~ \theta_{}  ~$ . How do I interpret it?

**p.s**

I have to go to bed in 10 minutes.

Comment: From where do you find this excerpt?

Comment: From the problem of magnet bars. Electromagnetism.

Comment: The bars indicate a positive only value. If the angle is negative (in the case of Hx being negative), then $|\theta|$ will be equal to $-\theta$. It looks as though $M1$ ~ $M2$ may be equivalent to $|M1 - M2|$

Comment: Probably a misprint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  \tan \left( -\theta_{}  \right) =-\tan \left( \theta_{}  \right)     $$

$$  \tan \left( \theta_{}  \right) =\frac{  M_{1}-M_{2}  }{ M_{1}+ M_{ 2 }    }  $$

$$ \therefore ~~ \theta_{} = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }   }{  M_{ 1 } +M_{ 2 }   }  \right)  $$

$$
    \theta_{} = 
\begin{cases}
    \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }   }{  M_{ 1 } +M_{ 2 }   }  \right) &~  \left( M_{ 1 } \geq M_{ 2 } \right)     \\\\
    \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  -\left| M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }  \right|   }{  M_{ 1 }+ M_{ 2 }    }  \right)  &~   \left( M_{ 1 } \leq M_{ 2 } \right) 
\end{cases}
$$

$$
    = 
\begin{cases}
    \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{ \left|  M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 } \right|    }{  M_{ 1 } +M_{ 2 }   }  \right) &~  \left( M_{ 1 } \geq M_{ 2 } \right)     \\\\
    \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  -\left| M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }  \right|   }{  M_{ 1 }+ M_{ 2 }    }  \right)  &~   \left( M_{ 1 } \leq M_{ 2 } \right) 
\end{cases}
$$

$$
    = 
\begin{cases}
    \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{ \left|  M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 } \right|    }{  M_{ 1 } +M_{ 2 }   }  \right) &~  \left( M_{ 1 } \geq M_{ 2 } \right)     \\\\
    -\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  \left| M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }  \right|   }{  M_{ 1 }+ M_{ 2 }    }  \right)  &~   \left( M_{ 1 } \leq M_{ 2 } \right) 
\end{cases}
$$

$$ = \pm \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  \left| M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }  \right|   }{  M_{ 1 } + M_{ 2 }   }  \right)  $$

$$   \therefore ~~ \left| \theta_{}  \right| =\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  \left| M_{ 1 } -M_{ 2 }  \right|   }{  M_{ 1 } + M_{ 2 }   }  \right)   $$

Comment: My environment of markdown preview has showed with no such brackets in the post of answer...

Comment: Try `$$`...`$$` instead of `\[`...`\]`. This is one of many (usually minor) differences between MathJax and LaTeX. Also, I find `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}` very helpful to keep the = signs lined up in a sequence of equations like this.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the post of answer.