# How does tilde work in equation of intersecting curves

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I found a topic in tangents and normals which called angle between two intersecting curves. When I turned my page. I saw that they had used tilde in most of equation. But, I totally don't know how tilde works. Does it work like negative? What does this tilde mean in intersecting curves (equation)? Without knowing it I can't understand any equation. I was seeing some problems. But, I don't know what they did to tilde.

$$\theta = tan^{-1}\frac{f'(x)\sim F'(x)}{1+f'(x)F'(x)}$$

Comment: For your information, tilde in MathJax can be typeset using the command `\sim`. Also, it may be easier if you show what part uses the tilde character.

Comment: Please provide a picture or screenshot of the source.

Comment: @soupless I just used something just like this $~$ (~).. I had written again inside mathjax..$\sim$ (Ohh It's working using \
sim)

Comment: To give an example, `$\sim$` should render as $\sim$.

Comment: @Blue I have gave an equation.. If it is not helpful than, I will add more equation...

Comment: The equation helps. Interestingly, I think a question very much like this was asked recently. Let me do some checking ...

Comment: The argument of $\tan^{-1}$ seems to be similar to the tangent of the difference of two angles, $$\tan(\alpha  - \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha - \tan \beta}{1 + \tan\alpha\tan\beta}.$$ I am not sure, I'll leave this to Blue.

Comment: I have found an example where they used tilde as minus.. So, I am going to do that..

Comment: @Istiak I recommend that you remove the part where you said that "Unfortunately, when I am using tilde..."

Comment: Found it: ["What does the tilde ('$\sim$') mean in $\tan^{-1}\frac{M_1\sim M_2}{M_1+M_2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4193397/409). The asker self-answered, and (if I'm reading correctly) seems convinced that the tilde is being used as an alternative for absolute value.

Comment: @Blue Beautiful... I am voting to close my question than..